Mocking the window object causes error Cannot read properties of null (reading '_history') at Window.get history [as history]
I have a Vue component with the following method that I am trying to unit test:
const close = () => {
  (window.open('', '_self').opener=window).close()
}

My test looks like this:
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } = from "vue-router";

describe('test suite', async () => {
let router
let wrapper

beforeEach(async () => {
    router = createRouter({
        history: createWebHistory(),
        routes: routes
    })

    wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
        global: {
            plugins: [router]
        }
    })
})

  test('window.close is called when btn is clicked', async () => {
    const windowSpy = vi.spyOn(window, 'open').mockReturnValue({
        close: vi.fn()
    })
    const btn = wrapper.find('[name="BTN_1"]')
    await btn.trigger('click')
    expect(windowSpy).toHaveBeenCalledOnce()
  })

})

The test succeeds, however it outputs an error message in the console:
[Vue Router warn]: Unexpected error when starting the router: TypeError: Cannot read properites of null (reading '_history') at Window.get history [as history]


It is jsdom that provides window to Node environment in Vitest.
The problem is there's an error in this piece of code caused by shorthand syntax:
(window.open('', '_self').opener=window).close()
close is called on window and not window object that is returned by open (which would be window in a browser in this case any way).
As explained here,

running code on the jsdom after closing it is not supported, so this is working as intended.

In order to be used with existing code, it should be modified to:
const w = window.open('', '_self');
w.opener = window;
w.close();

Or the test should be changed to:
const windowOpenSpy = vi.spyOn(window, 'open').mockReturnValue({});
const windowCloseSpy = vi.spyOn(window, 'close').mockReturnValue(undefined);

Also it's more convenient to use createMemoryHistory in tests because it doesn't require a cleanup.
